# Prevent 2 threads from reading/writing to the same file at the same time?

Tags: javascript, filesystemobject

I have several modules which all need to read a number from the same overall queueFile.txt. Each time a module reads the number in the file, it needs to add 1 to the number and then write the new number back to the file. The modules work very quick (only a few milliseconds for tasks sometimes)

I only want one module to be able to read and write to queueFile.txt at a time. If a module is reading/writing to the queueFile.txt, I want the other modules to wait until it has finished and then it's their turn.

I have tried two methods for this so far. Both involve creating a lock file while queueFile.txt is in use.

Method 1: This uses errors being thrown to determine if the queue lock file has already been opened for writing. If it hasn't, the module will open the queue lock file itself and then go to work on the main queue file and then close the queue lock file once it's done. If it has been opened, the modules will try 10000 times to open the queue lock file and then throw a message if it's still unsuccessful.

e.g.:

```
var count = 0;
var maxTries = 10000;
while(true) {
try {

    var queueLock = fso.OpenTextFile("queueFileLock.txt", 2, true);
   break;

} catch (err) {

    if (++count == maxTries){

       alert("Could not unlock queue file!");
    }
}
}

// do operation on queueFile.txt


//then close the lock
queueLock.close();

// then next module does its work
```

Method 2: This involves checking to see if a queue lock file exists. If it doesn't, then the module creates a queue lock file and goes to work on the main queue file. If a queue lock file does exist, then the module will wait for the active module to delete the queue lock file at the end of its operation.

e.g:

```
if((fso.FileExists("queueFileLock.txt"))==false){


var tempWrite = fso.OpenTextFile("queueFileLock.txt", 2, true);
    tempWrite.Close(); 


  }else{

while(fso.FileExists("queueFileLock.txt")){
      sleep(((1000*Math.random())+1000));

      }

  }

// do operation on queueFile.txt

//then close the lock
fso.DeleteFile("queueFileLock.txt") 

// then next module does its work
```

Using only one or 2 modules, the above methods appear to work fine. However, I want it to be flawless when using 20 modules or so. The above methods sometimes allow 2 or more modules to access the main queue file at the same time, which messes everything up.I'm not sure how this happens, because only one module should be able to open a text file for writing at a time, but this does not appear to be the case when lots of modules are running. Maybe its an error with Windows filesystemobject but I'm not sure. I have even tried the two methods above together but still, 2 or modules are sometimes able to access queueFile.txt at the same time.

Any ideas on how to fully prevent two modules accessing the queuefile.txt at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

I used myself this module async-lock to lock threads from updating same object to database. I think it canbe relevant to your case as well.

Comment: Okay thanks I'll take a look. The issue is I'm running my script in a .HTA, not using node.js so I'm not sure if I can add the async-lock library. I'll have a try.